# Is there a way to reformat braces automatically with Vim?

Tags: formatting, vim

I would like to reformat some code which looks like this :

```
if (cond) {
  foo;
}
```

to

```
if (cond)
{
  foo;
}
```

Since this is C code, I have been looking at `cindent`/`cinoptions` to use with `=` but it seems it does not deal with multiline rules.

I have been looking at `formatoptions`to use with `gq`, and it does not seem to be possible either.

So is it possible using default Vim options or should I use a specific plugin or function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/^\(\s*\).*\zs{\s*$/\r\1{/
```

Breakdown:

`^\(\s*\)` = capture the whitespace at the beginning of the line

`.*` = everything else

`\zs` = start replacement after this

`{` = open curly brace

`\s*$` = trailing whitespace before line end

`\r\1{` = newline, captured whitespace, brace

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this completely solves your problem, but if this is a one-shot operation, you might want to try regular expressions:

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)\(.*)\)\s*{\s*$/\1\2^M\1{/
```

Note that `^M` is a control character that is usually generated (depending on your terminal) by pressing <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments by Jay and Zyx, `\r` is a better way of inserting a line break into the replaced string. I wasn't aware of that, many thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why use `^M`? What about `\r`?

Comment: It does work but I would have preferred if it was accessible through an existing option. Still I could use your regexp in a user defined function mapped to <Leader> + something. If there is no other solution, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: @Jay: because that does not work on *all* machines I'm working on, but that's a good option if you're working on MacOS only.

Comment: @soulmerge. You are wrong: for historical reason `\r` in replacement means «split line in two at this point», not `\x0D`, see `:h s/\r` if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Zyx: Thanks for the info, didn't know that. No need to be so aggressive, though. @Jay: didn't know that `\r` translates to the native line break character(s), I'll sure use that from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you install [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)  you can do something like:

```
:set formatprg=astyle\ -b
```

Then use [`gq`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq) to reformat chunks of code.*emphasized text*

If you want this enabled every time you edit a C file,
you can add the following to your `.vimrc` file.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.c set formatprg=astyle\ -b
```

Comment: I suggest replacing `BufNewFile,BufRead *.c` with `FileType c`. Or even putting this into `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`.

Comment: Good call, but why `ftplugin` vs `after/ftplugin`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it within vim itself, but you can try the BSD `indent` command with the `-bl` option. With the cursor on the first `{`, you can type <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>`indent -bl`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.