# vimrc brackets/parenthesis java,c indentation new line

Tags: java, vim, code-formatting

If the code we have looks like

```
for(...){

}
```

after reformatting I'd like it to look like

```
for(...)
{

}
```

as well for all functions, methods, classes etc.
I found something similar in other article in stackoverflow but it was a regular expression and needed to type every time in the vim console. And I am looking for something to put in the vimrc file (if possible) and to work every time I open it.

Well this is the one I've found:

```
:%s/^(\s*).*\zs{\s*$/\r\1{/
```

in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463211/is-there-a-way-to-reformat-braces-automatically-with-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463211/is-there-a-way-to-reformat-braces-automatically-with-vim) but the thing is it adds a new line even if the bracket is on the right place... and still don't know how to map it to key combination.

Comment: Why don't you show that substitution so that we can help you turn it into a convenient mapping?

Comment: Well this is the one I've found :%s/^\(\s*\).*\zs{\s*$/\r\1{/ in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463211/is-there-a-way-to-reformat-braces-automatically-with-vim

but the thing is it adds a new line even if the bracket is on the right place... and still don't know how to map it to key combination.

Comment: Please, place it in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited with a more accurate pattern)

This should do the trick:

```
nnoremap <F9> :%s/^\(\s*\).\+\zs{\ze\s*$/\r\1{<cr>
```

But it it doesn't really sound "safe" to me.

Instead, you could do:

```
nnoremap <F9> :%s/^\(\s*\).\+\zs{\ze\s*$/\r\1{/c<cr>
```

which will ask for a confirmation for each match.

Or record a macro and play it back using `:global`.

***edit***

Your pattern, `:%s/^(\s*).*\zs{\s*$/\r\1{/`, is wrong because:

- the capture parentheses are not properly escaped, `(\s*)` instead of `\(\s*\)`
- `.*` would match *any* number of any character, including `0` which is why the substitution also works on lines with a single `{`.

Comment: Ok, when I map it like that it screams that it cannot find the pattern %s/^(\s*).*\zs{\ze\s*$

Comment: That's because the pattern you provided is wrong, the parentheses should be escaped.

Comment: Thank you! :) 
Btw I didn't even know it is possible to ask which ones to change.. Thanks :)))

Comment: Don't forget to check this answer if it helped you.